# Obtain solutions in Gekko by slightly relaxing constraints

Tags: python, gekko

I have a modified version of the [spring optimization Gekko model](http://apmonitor.com/me575/index.php/Main/SpringDesign).

Is there a way to slightly relax constraints so that the solver can still give me solutions even if they start falling out of the range of my constraints?

I'm aware of RTOL, but is there a way of specifying tolerances for individual equations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is create a new variable `eps` that has a lower bound of zero and an upper bound that is the maximum allowable violation. This becomes the deviation of the inequality constraints that can be minimized with an `importance` factor (e.g. 10).

```py
eps = m.Var(lb=0,ub=0.5)
m.Minimize(10*eps)
```

Here are modified equations with `eps`:

```py
m.Equations([
    d_coil / d_wire >= 4-eps,
    d_coil / d_wire <= 16+eps
    ])
```

[image: full script]

and the full script:

```py
from gekko import GEKKO

# Initialize Gekko model
m = GEKKO()

#Maximize force of a spring at its preload height h_0 of 1 inches
#The stress at Hs (solid height) must be less than Sy to protect from damage

# Constants
from numpy import pi

# Model Parameters
delta_0 = 0.4 # inches (spring deflection)
h_0 = 1.0 # inches (preload height)
Q = 15e4 # psi
G = 12e6 # psi
S_e = 45e3 # psi
S_f = 1.5 
w = 0.18

# Variables
# inches (wire diameter)
d_wire = m.Var(value=0.07247, lb = 0.01, ub = 0.2) 
# inches (coil diameter)
d_coil = m.Var(value=0.6775, lb = 0.0) 
# number of coils in the spring
n_coils = m.Var(value=7.58898, lb = 0.0) 
# inches (free height spring exerting no force)
h_f = m.Var(value=1.368117, lb = 1.0) 
F = m.Var() # Spring force

# Intermediates
S_y = m.Intermediate((0.44 * Q) / (d_wire**w))
h_s = m.Intermediate(n_coils * d_wire)
k = m.Intermediate((G * d_wire**4)/(8 * d_coil**3 * n_coils))
kW = m.Intermediate((4 * d_coil - d_wire)/(4 * (d_coil-d_wire)) \
                    + 0.62 * d_wire/d_coil)
n = m.Intermediate((8 * kW * d_coil)/(pi * d_wire**3))
tau_max = m.Intermediate((h_f - h_0 + delta_0) * k * n)
tau_min = m.Intermediate((h_f - h_0) * k * n)
tau_mean = m.Intermediate((tau_max + tau_min) / 2)
tau_alt = m.Intermediate((tau_max - tau_min) / 2)
h_def = m.Intermediate(h_0 - delta_0)
tau_hs = m.Intermediate((h_f - h_s) * k * n)

# Equations
eps = m.Var(lb=0,ub=0.5)
m.Minimize(10*eps)

m.Equations([
    F == k * (h_f - h_0),
    d_coil / d_wire >= 4-eps,
    d_coil / d_wire <= 16+eps,
    d_coil + d_wire < 0.75,
    h_def - h_s > 0.05,
    tau_alt < S_e / S_f,
    tau_alt + tau_mean < S_y / S_f,
    tau_hs < S_y / S_f
    ])

# Objective function
m.Maximize(F)

# Send to solver
m.solve()

# Print solution
print('Maximum force: ' + str(F[0]))
print('Optimal values: ')
print('d_wire : ' + str(d_wire[0]))
print('d_coil : ' + str(d_coil[0]))
print('n_coils : ' + str(n_coils[0]))
print('h_f : ' + str(h_f[0]))
print('eps : ' + str(eps[0]))
```